# create/match tree structures with and without common root nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, tree, cypher

I am trying to recreate a tree structure (java packages in this case but could also be directory hierarchies or anything else) matching common starting nodes and diverging where the paths differ. Obviously same named  leaf nodes are not the same nodes.

For example: `a.b.c.d` will turn into `(a)-(b)-(c)-(d)`. also, `a.b.c` will turn into `(a)-(b)-(c)`: same base, therefore part of the path.

I tried the following:

```
unwind ['a.b.c.d', 'x.a.b.c'] as pkg 
with split(pkg, '.') as packages 
foreach (idx in range(0, size(packages) - 2) | 
  merge (pkg1:Package{name: packages[idx]}) 
  merge (pkg2:Package{name: packages[idx+1]}) 
  merge (pkg1)<-[:IN_PACKAGE]-(pkg2) 
)
```

that works quite well so far until I add some structure such as `x.a.b` then its `a.b` nodes are matched with the `a.b` nodes of `a.b.c.d`. The result is currently: `(x)-(a)-(b)-(c)-(d)` while it should be two distinct paths: `(a)-(b)-(c)-(d)` and `(x)-(a)-(b)`. I see the problem, that is that each package is matched separately, not in context starting from the first node.

a path such as `(a)-(b)-(c)-(e)` and `(a)-(b)-(c)-(d)` should result in

```
(a)-(b)-(c)-(d)
          \-(e)
```

so how does one match common starting nodes?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. What is wrong with `(x)-(a)-(b)-(c)-(d)` being the resulting tree? Also, your query does not return any paths, so what paths are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The better approach here is for each :Package node to include the full package name (in addition to its subpackage). That allows package 'a.b.c.d' to be distinct from 'x.b.c.d'.

Unfortunately Neo4j doesn't have great support for text manipulation to break down the full packages at each level. You'll need APOC Procedures for this, and you'll need to jump through a few hoops to get here.

This query should do the trick

```
UNWIND ['a.b.c.d', 'a.b.c.e','x.b.c.d'] as pkg 
WITH pkg, split(pkg, '.') as packages
UNWIND range(1,size(packages)) as index
WITH packages[index - 1] as subpackage, apoc.text.join(packages[..index], '.') as myPkg, apoc.text.join(packages[..index - 1], '.') as parentPackage
WITH subpackage, myPkg, parentPackage
MERGE (package:Package{name:myPkg, subpackage:subpackage})
WITH package, parentPackage
WHERE parentPackage <> ''
MERGE (parent:Package{name:parentPackage})
MERGE (parent)<-[:IN_PACKAGE]-(package)
```